# Parallel 18650 battery pack voltage not stepping-up with Boost converter. Why?

Tags: boost, parallel, converter, step-up

I'm new here and I hope this is the right place to ask!

I have assembled a 6P 18650 battery pack out using Samsung 25R cells, soldered altogether with Nickel strips, effectively giving me 3.7V 15Ah.

I want to increase the voltage, so I hooked it up to a "XL6009 boost converter" module and also on a "250W 10A boost converter" module, both of which would not allow me to go anywhere near or above 5V!

This has lead me scratching my head and pulling hair out, as I do not understand why this is happening. Both lower and higher end modules are not able to "do the job", leaving me very confused.
I was wondering if anyone might know why this is the case? And what would I have to do if I want to step-up to 7-10V??

Thanks and I look forward hearing back!

---

Do you think it's simply because the input voltage is too low??

Comment: What sort of load are you testing this with?

Comment: This is a complicated kind of troubleshooting. At a first glance, the setup that you described _should_ work. But if it isnt't working, the classical reasons: 1) you connected the wires the wrong way; 2) the step-up modules are defective; 3) the batteries are dead, or empty. There's not much more to be said, because you gave few information about the subject. You should start troubleshooting testing every piece of the setup separately.

Comment: Reading XL6009 datasheet tells me that the minimun input voltage is **5 V**.

Comment: NPE - I've tested it with my LED setup in parallel, and with a multimeter measuring directly on the output of the moldules for voltage.

Comment: mguima - 1) Wires are definitely not connected the wrong way.
2) Modules are not defective, I've tested/used them for other things within this project and they do work, I mean two faulty boost converters obtained at different times, I must be very unlucky then :(
3) Batteries were charged before assembly, and still gives me a reading of 4.2V.

Comment: Long Pham - I just brought up the datasheet too and yes it says 5V but a lot of other places gave me lower minimum input voltages. Also, with my 250W boost converter I was still able to boost the voltage of another battery awhile ago that had a lower voltage than its minimum requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to assume that you are using some sort of XL6009-based converter module that has all the required passives. I have no information about the other module you are using.

A quick look at the [XL6009 data sheet](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf) shows that the minimum operating voltage is 5V. Although there would be a bit of design wiggle room, there is no expectation that it would operate below that.

There are [other options](https://www.pololu.com/product/2117) that might work with your application.

Comment: Edgar Brown - Thanks for that! 

The other module is this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/DC-DC-Boost-Converter-Step-up-Constant/dp/B01M3MVD58

I don't know exactly what chips it uses (yet) but I hope this helps!

I've checked the "other option" module you've linked, and I might give it a go but it's max current is only 1.4A.
I'm not entirely sure of its inner workings but I was hoping to operate the circuit on 4A at 12V. Do you think this is possible with this perhaps??

Comment: @Omar That module specifies on its Amazon page that the Input voltage has to be in the 8.5-48V range. A quick search found this one, based off an LM2587, (https://www.banggood.com/LM2587-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-5A-3-30V-Step-Up-to-4-35V-Power-Supply-Module-p-1135387.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: Yes, however as previously mentioned, i was able to take a (NP-F) battery at 7.4V and be able to increase the voltage.

Your search was a pretty good shout! My only concern is how will I be able to adjust the current more specifically to my needs? I.e. 4A?

Comment: You don't have to "adjust" the current (unless you are talking about adding current limiting, which some DC-DC modulators allow). Your actual load will determine how much current is drawn from a constant-voltage supply.

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant, Current Limiting. the 250W module does allow current limiting (it has two potentiometers) but the XL6009 moldule and the one you suggested only allows for adjusting voltage. Is there no way to limit the current specifically to a certain amp value??

In my OP I stated I've assembled a 6P 18650 battery pack out using Samsung 25R cells, soldered altogether with Nickel strips, which I believe it'll give me 3.7V 15Ah. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: May I ask, how would I go about current limiting a boost converter to only 4A from the power been supplied from my battery pack perhaps??

Comment: If you can’t find a module off the shelf and you can’t find an all-in-one pcb-mount DC-DC module, you can build your own converter module using a controller IC that supports current limitation. Alternatively you can opt to build a current measurement circuit that shuts down the module if a threshold is exceeded. Or you can just use a “resettable fuse”. Fold back current limiting, which is probably what you are thinking of, would be trickier to achieve.

Comment: Ahhh I sincerely wish I was that clever to build my own, I hoped it was also as simple as adding a potentiometer to the circuit to limit current itself (wishful thinking).

What I was thinking of doing was supplying power from my battery pack only 50W to my load, could I do this by either at 12V 4.1A and 10V 5A??

Comment: It is possible that some module uses the right part but either (1) did not implement current limiting or (2) used it to limit the output of the module. If it’s the former, it might be tricky to modify the module. If it’s the later, it can be as simple as swapping one resistor. Yes, switching DC-DC converters consume constant power from their power supplies (modulo efficiency changes due to the input voltage) but I guess you meant 4.17A@12V

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, things were pretty hectic for me the past few weeks!
It's a shame that the smaller modules do not have the current limiting feature, so far I haven't seen one person effectively modify a module to have an a simple current limiting feature. 
Also I forgot to mention that I've actually ordered that module back in late October and still waiting for it. Since it's only capable at 5A, I would have to do 5A@10V, right?

Comment: I thought to keep you lot posted as I can inform you and others that the Boost converter that you recommended has arrived (well a few days ago)!

So I just tried it and yes I am able to go more than 5V, thus it was probably because its minimum input voltage was lower than my source (batteries). 

However I've come across another problem, I have measured the current of my load, which the 20 LEDs at 1050mA are connected in parallel would effectively give me 21A, but I am only getting 0.7A on my multimeter!
Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have I hit a brick wall or something?? 


Anyone at all may i ask??? :(