# Parallel LED not achieving expected current from 18650 battery pack and Boost converter

Tags: boost, parallel, converter, step-up

This is kinda a follow up to a previous question I asked here: [Parallel 18650 battery pack voltage not stepping-up with Boost converter. Why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402318/parallel-18650-battery-pack-voltage-not-stepping-up-with-boost-converter-why)

I have now added the correct boost converter to my 20 LED and I am able to achieve higher voltages, however when I measure the current from the output of the booster converter and the wired LEDs, I am not getting the expected current, thus not getting the full power out of it.

My setup is:

- 20 x LED (12V, 1050ma) (Parallel circuit)
- 6P 18650 battery pack (Samsung 25R 3.7V, 2500mah)
- LM2587 Boost converter - 5A (https://www.banggood.com/LM2587-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-5A-3-30V-Step-Up-to-4-35V-Power-Supply-Module-p-1135387.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

So, if I am correct, my LEDs (as it's laid out) should consume 12V at 21A?
And my battery pack should supply 3.7V at 15A?
Correct me if I am wrong.

I have no intentions of delivering the full 15A or 21A (the latter being impossible) but at 12V at 4A or 10V at 5A.
However, my current readings are always giving me 0.7A on my multimeter!

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

[image: 20 LED setup]

[image: 6P Battery pack]

Comment: What are you using for a battery protection circuit?  What is it's current limit?  Your boost converter is not well documented (they even have mislabeled terminals in one of their images), but note that some boost converters output current at a given voltage is limited by input voltage.

Comment: @KH At the moment I am just directly connecting the terminals, I do have battery protection (as seen in the photo) but I had to disconnect it from the circuit when I discovered i wasn't getting the correct readings.

Sorry, I should've posted this link for the boost converter, as this is the one I actually bought from: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/LM2587-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-3-30V-Step-up-to-4-35V-Power-Supply-Module-MAX-5A/253023551848?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: You're using the wrong kind of power supply for that LED module. You need a constant-current LED driver, not a constant-voltage power supply. 1050mA is typical for commercial LED drivers. In all likelihood you'll need to give it at least 15-18V

Comment: @brhans Could a constant-current boost converter suffice?

Comment: I'm not going to do a side by side comparison, but I think that retailer may be offering even less information.  What's missing is a datasheet or performance graphs.  What is the actual output voltage of the converter with the LED load at 0.7A?  You may wish to experiment with varying input voltages and or a much smaller load to estimate the capabilities of the LED.  You could also reverse engineer the circuit.

Comment: brhans is correct of course.  Power LEDs require heatsinking and some form of current regulation.  An at least partially series arrangement of both LEDs and batteries would be wise.

Comment: @KH What is it you're looking for in the datasheets perhaps? I can't remember the voltage (it's been awhile since I measured it, my focus was on current) but I'll report on it asap.

Yes the LEDs would need heat dissipation if it were to run at its rated voltage and current, which is also the very reason why I decided to power it below its recommended ratings so they wouldn't heat up, even at that intended power the LED is super bright!

Comment: Just be careful.  If current control is not present, if there is not enough cooling, you could easily end up in thermal runaway on only some of the LEDs, resulting in a rapid cascade failure.  At significant power levels, it can be very easy to do this, and it can happen *very* quickly without a heatsink.

Comment: What you want from the datasheets are graphs that show rated output voltage vs current and vs input voltage.  This is and random quality are the main disadvantages to buying this kind of electronics.

Comment: @KH You're scaring me a bit! Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean exactly? Thermal runaway? Rapid cascade failure??

I'll also try and look for the datasheet!

Comment: Unlike most materials, LEDs resistance *decreases* when they heat up.  If you control them by steady voltage, this causes more current to flow through them and decreases their efficiency, causing them to heat up faster, which decreases their resistance, causing more current to flow, decreasing their efficiency, causing them to heat up faster, which decreases their resistance, causing more current to flow, decreasing their efficiency, causing them to heat up faster, which decreases their resistance, etc.  This describes thermal runaway.

Comment: High power LEDs (partly due to this, partly for other reasons(variations in current@given Vf) do not share current well in parallel (Although these shouldn't be too bad as they are series strings in themselves) and likely one LED will have more current across it than the rest, causing it to heat up and fail first, causing more energy to be available to the next worst LED, which in turn fails, ETC.  The change in voltage required to greatly change the current through an LED is very small as well, so it's easy to make a small adjustment to V, causing a great increase in I and cook your array.

Comment: These are FAKE specs. TI does not warrant them < 4V input and 5A is just a peak input not output with 3A input with adequate cooling as long as **Vout/Vin<3**  ( you are using >3 so bad performance) . Even the choke is rediculously small. The MCPCB maybe can handle about 2 W with 70'C Tj rise  or 250W for 1/125s (2W/(12V*21A). I agree with @Jack.. **Use 4S2P battery **only* use for flash photo**

Comment: Time and Current limited of course with pulse switch

Answer (score 1):

The unit you bought simply does **NOT** work for the application you have, and never can.

Your math is wrong as well, so lets start there:

I'll ignore heatsinks, conversion efficiency, circuit configuration etc etc.

> Your LEDs require 12V DC @ 21A ---> 252W at full power.

With an input voltage of 4.2V (fully charged cells) to supply 252W you would need to be able to supply 60A from your battery pack.

To achieve your goal you'd need a boost convertor that can supply 252W. The unit you [linked](https://www.banggood.com/LM2587-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-5A-3-30V-Step-Up-to-4-35V-Power-Supply-Module-p-1135387.html?cur_warehouse=CN) to shows little real details, but you can see that it is based on the TI [LM2587](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2587.pdf) IC.
Reference to the chip data shows that the 5A current capability turns out to be the **maximum peak current** that can be drawn on the INPUT side. This can be clearly seen from the block diagram, which shows the current sensing for the output switch:

[image]

Ignoring dozens of other elements in this design of a boost convertor, for you this indicates the absolute maximum input power could be 5A * 4.2V --> 21W (you can't actually ever get close to this for some of those other reasons, but I'm doing the shorthand version to show how far from reality you are).

So to summarize:

1. The boost convertor will not work for you since it CANNOT provide the power you need, even at reduced illumination.
2. The boost convertor is the wrong type of convertor to drive your LEDs. While the COB modules you seem to have CAN be voltage driven, you have to sense the module temperature accurately to do this. It is always better to use CC drive.
3. The battery pack is not large enough to power your LEDs for more than a few minutes even if the convertor would work.
4. The 0.7A (I assume here you are measuring the LED current) you see is about 8.5W, which is exactly what I'd anticipate in a convertor that is current limited in the way this unit is.

Back to the drawing board and work with some real values.

Perhaps as a starting point you could consider:

1. Build a 4SxP or 5SxP battery pack to suite the runtime you need at the current you need.
2. Use something like [this Buck convertor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-LM2596-HV-S-60V-3A-Buck-Constant-Current-Voltage-CC-CV-Step-Down-Module/201658287513) with one unit for **EACH INDIVIDUAL** LED. This unit allows the absolute voltage or current to be set (CC/CV) and they work quite adequately for this type of application.

It may also help to read some basic information on the COB LED modules, perhaps start [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2016/aug/the-basics-of-chip-on-board-cob-leds) or [here](http://ce.citizen.co.jp/lighting_led/dl_data/tech/en/Ref_P2468_0313_R3(0514).pdf). These modules are a simple series and parallel configuration of LEDs with NO current limiting other than their slope resistance. You need to carefully monitor the current, voltage and temperature of the module to get long term reliability.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer, it was incredibly insightful and helpful! I am still trying to understand everything but I do get the gist of it!

If it helps, this is the exact LED I have, the specs are on the page: https://tinyurl.com/y8vahzdx

Gathering from your summary, because the load my LED setup requires mean that I would need a boost converter (or driver) that could at least supply that power, even though I don't intend to use all of it. Am I correct on this matter??